# Putting boundaries and transforming variables (boolean python)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am at my beginning journey of learning python and I am struggling to get my head around transforming entries in a code.

I have a for loop going and for every loop I create 4 variables. So below is the result of four loops.

```
A    B   C    D
0    0   18   19
0    0   52   52
0    0   18   19
-1  -1   19   52 ** in this loop A have to be 0 , B have to be 0 and D have to be 50
-1  -1   19   20 ** in this case A and B must become 0
```

Expected result:

```
A    B   C    D
0    0   18   19
0    0   50   50 (## just a mark no need to be here just to point) , C and D became 50
0    0   18   19
0    0   19   52
0    0   19   20  ** A and B got transformed to 0
```

So I thought this would work, what I need is that none of this variables to be greater than 50 or below 0. If they are below zero they must become 0 and if they are above 50 then 50, else just the variable itself:

```
if A < 0:
     A = 0
elif A>50:
     A = 50
elif 0<A<50:
     A=A
elif A < 0:
     A = 0
elif B>50:
     B = 50
elif 0<B<50:
     B=B    ......
```

I also thought about defining a function and passing the 4 variables each time to the function..

Ok i edit the if , sorry typo. Let be a bit more clear on every run A,B,C and D must be transformed if they are above 50 or below zero, so just use a 0

Comment: The last elif should be `elif 0<B AND B<50:`   however, to me this last one might be a redundant statement. This also goes for the 2nd elif which should be `elif 0<A AND A<50:`

Comment: @GeorgeBou: `0<B and B<50` is equivalent (but slightly slower, as it loads `B` twice) to `0 < B < 50`; no need to split it up.

Comment: `elif if`??? That won't even pass syntax checks. You've also got a gap in your checks here. Think about what happens when `A` or `B` is `0` or `50`. That's not less than 0, greater than 50, or greater than 0 and less than 50, so none of your checks will catch it. Lastly, you haven't provided a [MCVE], so we have no idea what else is changing A/B/C/D, how you're looping, etc.

Comment: Assuming `elif if A < 0:` is meant to be a separate block from the previous (that is, the `elif` is wrong, it should be `if A < 0:`, you're testing/setting the wrong variable (the rest of the tests and sets are for `B`, not `A`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A = A` doesn't do anything so it is not needed.

There is an issue in that you mix the comparisons of `B` in with `A`, because of the `elif`. You should separate them:

```
if A < 0:
     A = 0
elif A > 50:
     A = 50

if B < 0:
     B = 0
elif B > 50:
     B = 50
```

In the end you could just write a reusable function:

```
def clamp(val, minval, maxval):
    if val < minval:
        return minval
    elif val > maxval:
        return maxval
    else:
        return val
```

And use it with:

```
A = clamp(A, 0, 50)
B = clamp(B, 0, 50)
C = clamp(C, 0, 50)
D = clamp(D, 0, 50)
```

Comment: perfect solution .. Thank you

Comment: The whole first part of this answer is wrong. `0<A<50` in Python does not evaluate like C does (where `0<A` would evaluate, then the resulting boolean value would be compared to 50). `0 < A < 50` is a [specifically, intentionally supported Python syntax for comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) that is roughly equivalent to `0 < A and A < 50` (except `A` is only loaded/computed once, not twice). While `A = A` is pointless, your first two paragraphs are otherwise 100% wrong.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I was unaware Python supports that notation (I do come from a C background). I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can be simplified to:

```
if A < 0:
   A = 0;
elif A > 50:
   A = 50;
```

.....

Saying A=A is redundant